# Javascript Function Defining Performance on Browsers

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, browser

Is there any browser performance difference between defining javascript functions before and after DOM loaded?

I usually define functions after DOM loaded like this

```
// Example-1

$(document).ready(function(){
  function foo(){
    alert("foo");
  }

  foo();
});
```

and some people use this way

```
// Example-2

function foo(){
  alert("foo");
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  foo();
});
```

Theory-1: They say Example-1 is slower than Example-2 because Example-1 waited DOM to load then started to define functions and then page became to work in full function. However, in Example-2 functions defined at the same time while DOM is loading so page became full function at the same time when DOM loaded. As a result Example-2 gained some time while Example-1 was trying to define functions.

Theory-2: $(document).ready function itself is slow. To get same result faster use this way

```
(function() {

})();
```

I couldn't find anything related to this theories. Could someone explain please what happens behind the scenes?

Thanks.

Comment: Time lost due to function declarations is negligible.  This code smells of premature optimization

Comment: A document.ready is essentially binding on an event that the browser emits once the DOM has been parsed, not when the images/videos/other resources have been loaded.  Once that event happens, the event handler is executed and your logic happens.  An Immediately Invoked Functional Expression (IIFE) is executed immediately, as the name says.  There is no delay.  The two approaches are not apples to apples.

Comment: More important might be what's called 'render-blocking javascript'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After that time I found that defining functions without `$(document).ready` is faster. What I couldn't realise browser already downloaded jQuery library and worked so fast when I am in local. When I go online it starts downloading the library first then define related functions.

Answer (score 0):

Any performance differences between example #1 and example #2 are irrelevant.  The meaningful difference is a matter of scoping.

As for your "Theory 2" function, all you're doing is creating a closure.  This is totally different than jQuery's `.ready()`, which is equivalent to waiting for the `DOMContentLoaded` event.